# Error While writing pyspark dataframe to MySQL database

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am getting the following error:

`"Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.<init>()"` while writing pyspark dataframe to mysql database

spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master yarn --conf spark.pyspark.python=/usr/bin/python3 --packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.12 s3://aramark-files/test_pyspark.py
```

And I am writing using:

```
df.write.jdbc(url="jdbc:mysql://dbhost/dbname", table="tablename", mode="append", properties={"user":"dbuser", "password": "s3cret"})
```

Below is the error I am getting after executing the above spark-submit command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/tmp/spark-8bb457ce-fc88-4384-af58-9e52e2d6e21a/test_pyspark.py", line 51, in <module>
    df.write.jdbc(jdbcUrl, where, mode='append', properties=dbProperties)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 942, in jdbc
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o79.jdbc.
: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:499)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: Is this in Hortonworks or Cloudera?

Comment: No.. I am using amazon emr spark

Answer (score 2):

I ran across the same problem in the Scala API. I'm reading from and writing to an Oracle 12c database, and both the DataFrameReader and the DataFrameWriter require the "driver" property to be set, in my case to "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", or else the former blows up with "No suitable driver" and the latter blows up with NoSuchMethodException.

I would therefore suggest you try

```
df.write.jdbc(url="jdbc:mysql://dbhost/dbname", table="tablename", mode="append", properties={"user":"dbuser", "password": "s3cret", "driver": "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" })
```

Where I've substituted the MySQL driver class name from [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html).

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Deepak_Spark_Beginner. You _could_ upvote my answer, for that matter raviraju could have accepted it, but the important thing is that you're happy.